# how to use com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Text

Tags: java, php, google-app-engine, quercus

i use  Quercus to run php on google app engine and and i use below code to insert value to the GAE datastore (BigTable).

```
<?php
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Entity;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceFactory;

$entity = new Entity("test"); 
$entity->setProperty('story',' --- more than 500 char ---');
$dataService = DatastoreServiceFactory::getDatastoreService();
$dataService->put($entity);
?>
```

but return flowing error because story value is more than 500 char.

```
error:
com.caucho.quercus.QuercusException: com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Entity.setProperty: story: String properties must be 500 characters or less. Instead, use com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Text, which can store strings of any length.
```

i don't know any thing about java.
Does anyone have any idea how to use [com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Text](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/Text.html) in my php code.

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Will this work?

```
<?php
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Entity;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceFactory;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Text;


$entity = new Entity("test"); 
$TextValue = new Text(' --- more than 500 char ---');
$entity->setProperty('story',$TextValue);
$dataService = DatastoreServiceFactory::getDatastoreService();
$dataService->put($entity);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing in a string for the second parameter of 'setProperty', create a new com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Text and pass that in.

It looks like you should know how to do that.

See the definition of 'setProperty' here:  http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/Entity.html